# Nand2tetris.The builtin gate chips behave strangly

Tags: nand2tetris

I am doing the projects of nand2tetris, from which we can build a virtual computer by basic logic gates with the simulator provided by their webpage. But I am confronted with a problem as shown here:

[image]

The outputs of "NOT" and "AND" gate are the inverse of what's expected in the red circle from the pictrue. For the "NOT" gate, if its input is 1, its output should be 0, but is 1. For "AND", if its inputs are both 1, its output should be 1, but is 0. In previous projects I've finished, there were no such erros. It's so strange. They both are building chips not built by myself, but output abnormally, which confused me so much. If I don't solve it, I don't think I can do the rest of projects of nands2tetris. It's really nice for someone to help me find the reason.

Comment: You'll need to explain in a lot more detail what you expect the results to be and what the results are. Your picture and explanation are really confusing to those of us who don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @user1118321 I'm sorry.I've edited a lot.Does my words look clearer now?

Comment: Yes, that's significantly better! Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't know the answer, but hopefully now someone who does can help out.

Comment: @user1118321 Thank you all the same for giving me such valuable advice.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're testing Multiplexor chip.

If you didn't move your Mux.hdl file out of its original source then by default it uses **your** implementation of And and Not gates. Check implementation of `And.hdl` and `Not.hdl` that are present in the same directory as your `Mux.hdl`.

You can be sure that built-in chips are implemented correctly if you got them from project's webpage, they are thoroughly tested.